# How can I convert character to date in r?

Tags: r

[image: the code]
[image: the current result]

As I have shown in picture 1 and 2, I want to convert my character data to date, but it return na, the problem is probably caused by %d in format. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `lubridate` package. There you have different functions doing what you intend. If your date format is for instance `"YYYY-MM-DD"` just use `ymd()`.

Comment: Nice first answer! To make things clearer, it's sometimes useful to add a toy example to prove your point.

Answer (score 1):

As @almost_thor said right, you can use the `lubridate` package. In your case you can use the `dmy` function like this:

```
df <- data.frame(LOS = c("18-Jun-11", "8-Mar-11", "25-Feb-11"))
library(lubridate)
dmy(df$LOS)
```

Output:

```
[1] "2011-06-18" "2011-03-08" "2011-02-25"
```